# Ripple Emulator alternatives

Tags: mobile, cordova, ripple

Are there any alternatives for Ripple Emulator (plugin for Chrome browser)? I'm interested also in plugins for other browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Ripple is the best option out there, but I'm also aware of Opera having their own mobile emulator product:

http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the built-in emulator in Chrome is now much better than Ripple.

You don't really need a 3rd party extension just for this.

Here's a snapshot for the emulator in Chrome v49:

[image]

Learn more: [Device Mode & Mobile Emulation | Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/)

Comment: Considered that the user asked for plugins, I don't think this qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @Malavos So, wouldn't you adapt if Chrome provides a similar and native functionality? There are a lot of people who don't know about this.

Comment: I'm not stating that - I'm just stating that this is not what OP asked, so it should not been an answer to this question. As you can see, I did not even gave you a -1 (actually fairly good) - because it's not a bad answer, but it's not a answer per se. Perhaps you should have posted that as a comment?

Comment: @Malavos I don't completely agree with you. This question was asked in 2012 and its 2015 now. Technologies evolve and I believe developers should adapt to that.

Comment: Considered that the user asked for plugins, I don't think this question qualifies as on-topic.

Comment: The question is divided in two parts.   A. Alternatives   B. "ALSO" plugins. Read it again please.

Comment: @Heroselohim I did read the question long time back. My answer clearly points to the browser's native functionality rather than installing something that offers same functionality. Ready my answer again please.

Comment: I was referring to the other users telling that the OP didn't required alternatives. Plugins were required as an additional information using the word "ALSO". So your solution is correct!